# Disable price cache

Tags: magento2, cache

I need to disable caching on all blocks displaying price, where can I disable this?
Clearing the cache whenever you charge some price will do.
Already tried to put cacheable = "false" in some blocks xml but nothing solved.

Magento 2.3.3
Win 10 Xampp, linux

Comment: I don't think cache is the problem. you probably need to rebuild the price index.

Comment: My price changes dynamically per customer who logs in but what happens is that the price that would be specific to one customer is showing up for another, which doesn't happen when the entire store cache is off

Comment: You shouldn't disable caching on these blocks. Especially `cacheable="false"` is a huge no-go because it will render the FPC useless. Instead, replace the price templates by a knockout-template. There are many tutorials on this concept. You can also ask another question once you encounter specific problems.